# What is a good way to introduce new players to Pathfinder without making things too linear?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques

I wanted to create a dungeon to get a new group of players together and teach them pathfinder, but I felt I wanted something more than 'go to the goblin cave and get the macguffin' for this first dungeon.

So, in your general Experiences to the DM's out there, what is a good way to introduce new players in without being cliched?

Comment: Wouldn't this really depend mostly on your players? "Solve the soup cans" is not foreign to D&D and PF, although a lot of players aren't terribly fond of puzzles that their character attributes can't help with. So we'd need to know what your group likes.

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a dungeon to introduce the group, but the idea made me wonder. I wanted to make a dungeon ready for a group early, but I was also curious about this zelda-ish idea.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We aren't a traditional discussion forum and deal with specific answerable questions - this is asking for people's opinions, which is off topic.  You could ask a similar question if you were to say more precisely what kind of thing you wanted to do and why, and then ask for pros and cons from thos who have actually done that thing.

Comment: 'non-cliche setting/method to introduce new players to rpgs using pathfinder with a non-linear/open-world storytelling method' is a finite, answerable question that creates a useful resource in answering it.  So i've voted to re-open.